# Why does setting gateway on minion to 10.0.1.0 fail on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the guide here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.md

to setup a Kubernetes cluster of 1 master and 2 minions. After following through all the steps, when I create a pod it gets scheduled to a minion but continues to be in the Pending state.

When I look at the Kubelet log in the minion, I see this error:

`Jan 24 00:46:21 localhost.localdomain kubelet[2356]: E0124 00:46:21.042058    2356 kubelet.go:906] Error syncing pod, skipping: API error (500): Cannot start container fa6cbc76fe336aca5f9a341c8cf71ad4ba3aec83e276e340d0e5de16a0052001: setup networking set gateway to 10.0.1.0 on device eth0 failed with invalid argument`

The network on my master looks like this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.109.82  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.109.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe0b:bb1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:0b:0b:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2822228  bytes 201486806 (192.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1527270  bytes 143886867 (137.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

On the minion the network looks like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.109.83  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.109.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe0b:bb0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:0b:0b:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2207203  bytes 164668744 (157.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 777356  bytes 65960933 (62.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

kbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.0  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 42 (42.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Would anyone have any hints of what could be going wrong here ?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please let me know - why the down-vote to this question ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The top of the guide you link to says "This guide will only get ONE minion working. Multiple minions requires a functional networking configuration done outside of kubernetes."

Have you done any special networking configuration (like [flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel)) for your cluster?

If you want to use Fedora, you might have better luck following the [Fedora + Ansible](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_ansible_config.md) instructions instead of the manual instructions.